# How to merge duplicate contact records in a .pst

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts, merge, pst

Here's my problem: Once I merge my two .pst files I will have one file with a large number of contact records that are 'duplicates' in the sense that the records share the same contact name field, but are not really duplicates because they don't share exactly the same information in other fields in the records.

Is there a way to merge these pseudo-duplicates such that in fields where there's a conflict of field information, the latest entry prevails?

My .pst file will be quite large after the merge, so solutions that involve examining each pair of duplicates manually would be impractical.

Comment: There are Outlook add-ons that handle duplicate contacts like this.

Comment: @Ramhound Any specific suggestions?

Comment: The products I am aware of can easily be found by doing a Google search.